# array_walk trying to write to outside array

Tags: php, array-walk

I have a simple piece of code that isn't working as I would expect it would, could someone please explain why it isn't populating the fields array and how to solve it.

```
$fields = [];

array_walk($class->properties, function($v, $k) use ($fields) {
    $fields[] = $v->name;
});

die(var_dump($fields));

// output is []
```

Comment: Pass by reference in the `use`, not by value: `array_walk($class->properties, function($v, $k) use (&$fields){$fields[] = $v->name;});`

Comment: worth pointing out for this usecase, the function `array_map` would have been a better choice.

Comment: the die() with the var_dump() is gratuitous.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$fields = [];

array_walk($class->properties, function($v, $k) use (&$fields) {
    $fields[] = $v->name;
});

die(var_dump($fields));
```

After I wrote this I saw Mark Baker comment. That's the right answer.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `array_map()`:

```
$fields = array_map(function($v) {
    return $v->name;
}, $class->properties);

die(var_dump($fields));
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates a class whose sole property *properties* contains an array of objects, each of which has a name property, as follows:

```
<?php

$class = new stdClass;
$class->properties = [new stdClass,new stdClass, new stdClass];

$class->properties[0]->name = "Anne";
$class->properties[1]->name = "Bob";
$class->properties[2]->name = "Robin";

$fieldsA = [];
$fieldsB = [];

if ( array_walk( $class->properties, function( $o ) use ( &$fieldsA ){ 
                                      $fieldsA[] = $o->name;
                                    }) ) {
   echo "\nMission accomplished:\n";
   var_dump($fieldsA);
}

$fieldsB = array_map(  function( $e ) {
                                      return $e->name;
                                      },$class->properties);
if (count($fieldsB) > 0) {
   echo "\nMission accomplished:\n";
   var_dump( $fieldsB );
}
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/Z7Alb#output)

As you may note, both [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map) will produce the same results of stuffing a new array with the names that the three objects contain.  Array_map() offers more simplicity than array_walk() which requires a use variable and a reference operator.  Also, the return value of array_map() is a brand new array if all goes well.  So, I concur with @localheinz and recommend it as the better choice.

Note: regarding the callback, it is unnecessary to specify value, key parameters.  Both of these built-in functions examine each element of *properties*.  Specifying `function( $v, $k )` would be helpful if the code needed to do something with an element's key.